# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: boot, kernel

When I start ubuntu I get this error : "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules".
After entering "sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" I get this result:

[image: see picture]

Would you be so kind to help me?

```
$ dmesg | grep -i failed
[    0.483715] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WLBU._STA] (Node ffff9bc91a8b60c8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160422/psparse-542)
[    0.483825] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WLBU._STA] (Node ffff9bc91a8b60c8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160422/psparse-542)
[    0.486316] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[    0.579346] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WLBU._STA] (Node ffff9bc91a8b60c8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160422/psparse-542)
[    0.691710] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WLBU._STA] (Node ffff9bc91a8b60c8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160422/psparse-542)
[   17.817385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.817427] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
```

Comment: if you have nvidia driver installed this might happen. 
Check your /etc/modules file if there is a line containing nouveau then
 commenting out (using the '#' character) both lines with nouveau. after that reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Comment: I have a HP 255 G5 laptop and the "secure boot" is disabled by default. Thanks for your reply

Comment: In `terminal`, type `dkms status` and lets see if it gives us an answer.

Comment: It doesn't show anything..

Comment: OK, try this... reboot, then immediately open `terminal` and type `dmesg | grep -i failed` and note the time of the failure message. Copy the date/time to your clipboard. Then type `grep "paste date/time inside these quotes" /var/log/syslog` and see if you can tell where it failed. Show me that output if you don't understand what you're seeing. Edit it into your question, not in the comments please.

Comment: Hum, that didn't work as expected. Try this... in `terminal` type `grep -i failed /var/log/syslog` looking for the kernel load failure message. If you find it, copy the date/time to your clipboard. Then type `grep "paste date/time inside these quotes" /var/log/syslog`. Make sure to alert me with a new comment that begins with `@heynnema` or I may miss what you've done.

Comment: Meanwhile I decided to return the notebook and buy another one. Thank you for your help