# Failed to start load modules at boot

Tags: kernel, lenovo

Failed to start load kernel modules

see `systemctl status systemd -modules-load.service` for details

[Failed to start Load Kernel Modules Ubuntu 16.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905586/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules-ubuntu-16-04-2)  is not working

**Edit1** (output of journalctl | grep modules):

```
Jun 14 10:57:33 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd-modules-load[255]: Failed to insert 'ashmem_linux': Exec format error
Jun 14 10:57:33 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd-modules-load[255]: Failed to find module 'binder_linux'
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd-modules-load[255]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd-modules-load[255]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd-modules-load[255]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 14 10:57:34 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 14 10:58:01 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 gnome-shell[1453]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js 538]: reference to undefined property properties[istr].arrayIndex
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
Jun 14 10:58:07 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
Jun 14 10:58:08 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1840]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
Jun 14 10:58:13 zodiac-Lenovo-G50-30 gnome-shell[2018]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js 538]: reference to undefined property properties[istr].arrayIndex
```

Comment: [edit] your question and give the output of `journalctl | grep modules`

Comment: `Secure boot` is disabled in your BIOS, yes? In `terminal` type `sudo systemctl status` and note if there are any "Failed " services. If there are, page down to find out which one. Then type `sudo systemctl status {enter service name here}`. Edit your question to include the results via copy/paste.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema, I am using legacy so secure boot is not an option. sudo systemctl status does say 2 failed but i am not able to find which are those processes.